# Devpak for Allegro 5

Tags: allegro5

Hello community of stackoverflow. I've been using Allegro 4 and Dev-C++ 5.5.3, until I noticed that there's a new and better version of the library avaliable. I tried to download and install Allegro 5, but I got confused with so many ways to do it, and I have to admit that I have no idea of building it with cmake or something, but it seems it requires to do a lot of downloading which I can't afford.

However, I heard that there's a DevPak version of Allegro 5 avaliable, some people (even in this community) declared that they downloaded the devpak version of the library, but I can't find a reliable link to download it no matter how much I search for it. Having it will make things a lot easier to me, so I wish you could give me a reliable and updated link to download the devpak, or at least to guide me through it's building and installation.

I've downloaded what I think is the allegro source code (maybe for building it) from [this link](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/releases/download/5.2.7.0/allegro-5.2.7.0.zip) but actually I don't know what to do with it. If you can help me with that version I downloaded, or at least guiding me to finally get the Allegro 5 library, I will thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used that 5.0.10 devpak for a long time. By the way, I don't think there is still people doing new devpaks.
You can download a pre-compiled version of allegro here: https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/releases

You may also need to download an updated version of mingw to match the allegro build you just downloaded. Then at Dev-C++ you create a new compiler set and configure the search paths to point to your mingw and allegro folders (use your current compiler set as a reference).

Comment: Thank you very much for the info, but in that page you just gave me there are many links and many downloads, and every one of them is not the precompiled allegro. I've been in the page before, but as I didn't know what link should help me, I downloaded the lightest one (which is the one I said I had no idea of what to do with it). If you can tell me what link I should download, I would appreciate that (plus I need a 32-bit compatible version) Can you help me with that? Thank you anyway

Comment: The precompiled builds are the ones with the longer file names. Let's say you want the lastest version for 32 bit architecture with dynamic linking (dll), then you should download allegro-i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-10.2.0-posix-dwarf-dynamic-5.2.7.0.zip
i686-w64 = 32 bits.
gcc-10.2.0-posix-dwarf = the compiler used to build it. You should use the same version (or newer).

Comment: Let's see... I downloaded that link that you told me (I'm sure I did it with the correct one) and upgraded my mingw 32 compiler. I linked the library with "-lallegro_monolith" (if it's not the correct one, please correct me) and it worked with no errors, but when I execute it, it shows me a system error with every allegro5 program I compile, something like  "Unable to find the entrance point to the procedure InitializeConditionVariable on the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll" and then closes. Is it because I downloaded the wrong compiler, or maybe because my windows xp? Thank you anyways

Comment: Windows xp could be the reason, can't say for sure. I would try running an already compiled game from allegro.cc to see if it runs or gives the very same error. You can also try running one of your compiled programs on a different machine with Windows 7 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seen that I've got no answers (searching the matter in Google results in this unanswered question) I'll post the link that I've found, hoping that it will be useful to anyone who has the same problem.
I've downloaded the devpak from this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/devpacks/files/allegro5-5.0.10-1aved.DevPak/download which is the version 5.0.10 of allegro, but as I noted, there's a newer release available (though I don't know if there's a devpak version of that one). If someone knows a way of getting a more updated devpak, please post it here anyway. However, I think that's something, and I hope it will help those in my situation